# Term for the spectral decomposition of a matrix where the transformation matrix is a product of Householder matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

I would like to use a term for a spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix, **A** = **QDQ'**, where **Q** is an orthogonal matrix which is given as a product of Householder reflectors. This should be something like "Householderized spectral decomposition", but the word "Householderized" does not exist. Do you have any suggestion for such a term?

Comment: A "reflectoral decomposition", perhaps? :-)

Comment: Thanks, or reflectorized decomposition, the word "reflectorize" seems to exist: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reflectorize.